# How to pass url as a value in a link using htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to pass a url through a link

My htaccess code is :

```
RewriteRule ^info/(.*)$ folder1/page1.php?url=$1 [L]
```

But my result is :

```
$_GET['url'] = http:/stackoverflow.com (one slash is missing , http:/)
```

I need $_GET['url'] as http://stackoverflow.com

How is it possible using htaccess?

Can someone help me plz.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If push comes to shove:

```
$_GET['url'] = str_replace('http:/', 'http://', $_GET['url']);
```

Answer (score 4):

I think Xzibit has a valid point on this:

[http://cdn.memegenerator.net/instances/400x/18286577.jpg http://cdn.memegenerator.net/instances/400x/18286681.jpg](http://cdn.memegenerator.net/instances/400x/18286681.jpg)

short story: use urlencode when you want to embed a url inside a link, i think it will fix your problem.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: @Micku Use urlencode in the script that creates the link. The link in your URL will then pass through htaccess without messing anything up, and the page that receives it can use urldecode to recover it.

Answer (score 1):

its not possible, `/` slash is url separetor. You must encode it before use as parameter. For example : `site.com/info/http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com`

```
$url = isset($GET['url']) ? urldecode($GET['url']) : 'default';
```

Or better dont use `http://`. And `site.com/info/stackoverflow.com`. In php:

```
$url = isset($GET['url']) ? 'http://'.$GET['url'] : 'default';
```

Answer (score 0):

Using RewriteRule to match URI will not work because Apache will strip multiple slash into 1. Here is the code that makes it possible using `%{THE_REQUEST}`:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+info/([^\s\?]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.php?url=%1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Sry its not wrking... am getting the same result ie http:/stackoverflow.com